# How to wait SparkContext to finish all process?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How do I see if SparkContext has contents executing and when everything finish I stop it? Because currently I am waiting 30 seconds before to call SparkContext.stop, otherwise my app throws an error.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object RatingsCounter extends App {

  // set the log level to print only errors
  Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

  // create a SparkContext using every core of the local machine, named RatingsCounter
  val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "RatingsCounter")

  // load up each line of the ratings data into an RDD (Resilient Distributed Dataset)
  val lines = sc.textFile("src/main/resource/u.data", 0)

  // convert each line to s string, split it out by tabs and extract the third field.
  // The file format is userID, movieID, rating, timestamp
  val ratings = lines.map(x => x.toString().split("\t")(2))

  // count up how many times each value occurs
  val results = ratings.countByValue()

  // sort the resulting map of (rating, count) tuples
  val sortedResults = results.toSeq.sortBy(_._1)

  // print each result on its own line.
  sortedResults.foreach { case (key, value) => println("movie ID: " + key + " - rating times: " + value) }

  Thread.sleep(30000)

  sc.stop()
}
```

Comment: scala = 2.11.8 and spark = 1.6.1

Comment: Can you share the object  your are putting your main function in ?

Comment: can you try instead of extends app to def main and also 1 in second argument for sc.textfile

Comment: I just want a way to receive a call back from SparkCOntext

Comment: Both @RamGhadiyaram and @eliasah are right - Spark applications shouldn't extend `App`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spark applications should define a `main()` method instead of extending `scala.App`. Subclasses of `scala.App` may not work correctly.

And since you are extending App, you are getting an unexpected behavior.

You can read more about it in the official documentation about [Self Contained Applications](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications).

`App` uses `DelayedInit` and can cause initialization issues. With the main method you know what's going on. [Excerpt from reddit.](https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/4zvelw/app_trait_vs_main_method/)

```
object HelloWorld extends App {
  var a = 1
  a + 1
  override def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(a) // guess what's the value of a ?
  }
}
```

Comment: I know how to define a main method on Scala. My problem, how was write on the question, is how to define a call back method from SparkContext.

Comment: You said that you are encountering an error if you don't add sleep. And I answered on why you are having a problem with your actual code. Now for the call back you'd need to use something like spark-jobserver as spark isn't capable of giving call back as any other heavy Scala application.

Comment: I believe that this is your error "Because currently I am waiting 30 seconds before to call SparkContext.stop, otherwise my app throws an error". And that is not because of the call back...

Comment: @FelipeOliveiraGutierrez This answer is correct. There's no need for a callback. If you implement the runnable Scala object with a `main` method, the main execution will block until Spark is done. Test it and then consider accepting this answer.